# HTML/CSS/JS Template or Plugin for article or post creation

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, web

I am developing a web solution where certain users can create articles that are post on the main feed of the application.

I wonder if there any plugin that lets me have a post/article creation interface similar to this?

[image]

The main point is having these options for Bold, Italic, Text Size and alignment, etc...

Does anyone knows a plugin that allows me to insert this kind of box?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE or CKEditor will be a good solution. I prefer TinyMCE, It's a very rich editor based on js.